# C++ Link List Program

Tags: c++, list

I have created the function below to sort a link list.  I am getting 3 error messages when trying to compile the program.

1. Line of code:   while(c != NULL && (c->iNam.compare(nam) < 0))

   request for member 'compare' in 'c->invtLst::iNam', which is of pointer type        'std::string*.
2. Line of code:   t->iNam.assign(nam);

   request for member 'assign' in 'c->invtLst::iNam', which is of pointer type 'std::string*
3. Line of code:   t->iNam.assign(nam);

   request for member 'assign' in 'c->invtLst::iNam', which is of pointer type 'std::string*

All the problems appear to be in my "void sortListF7(invtLst *c, string nam)
" function.  Could someone please help me what I have done wrong?

```
void sortListF7(invtLst *c, string nam)
{
invtLst *p, *t;
p = NULL;

while(c != NULL && (c->iNam.compare(nam) < 0))
{
    p = c;
    c = c->loc;
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        t = newNodeF4();
        t->iNam.assign(nam);
        p->loc = t;
        infile >> c->iNum >> c->iQty >> c->iPrc >> c->iSfStk;
        t->loc = c;
    }
    else
    {
        t = newNodeF4();
        t->iNam.assign(nam);
        t->loc = c;
        infile >> c->iNum >> c->iQty >> c->iPrc >> c->iSfStk;
        head = t;
    }
}
```

}

I am also using a struct for this program.

```
struct invtLst
{
    string *iNam;
    float iNum;
    float iQty;
    float iPrc;
    float iSfStk;
    float iPrcStck;
    float pNq;
    char flag;
    invtLst *loc;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iNam` is actually a pointer to string, while you are trying to assign it a string value.

If you can change the `struct invtLst`, then change the line from `string *iNam;` to `string iNam;`.

If you can not change the structure, then follow Smac89's answer. Use `c->iNam->compare(nam)` instead of `c->iNam.compare(nam)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  At first I was point *iNam to a char array.  I decide to change that array into a string, then past it to my sort function.  It is still not sorting correctly, but at it is compiling. Any suggestion on what is wrong on it?

Comment: In your code, `while(c != NULL && (c->iNam.compare(nam) < 0)` ensures that c is not null. So, when you assign `p = c;` and check the condition `if(p != NULL)`, it **NEVER** goes in the `else` section. May be this is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

All of the errors point to one thing:

iNam is of type pointer to string; so to access it you have to use the `->` operator or `* .`. So to get you started, where ever you try to use iNam in your code do it like `(*c->iNam).method` or `c->iNam->method`